# How should I setup circular refs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a small little problem in JavaScript. I would like to do the following:

```
var peter = {
  pet : spot
}

var spot = {
  owner : peter
}
```

The above code runs fine but peter.pet will be undefined. While spot.owner will be defined. IS there a better way then doing stuff like :

```
var peter = {
  pet : 'spot'
}

var spot = {
  owner : peter
}

peter.pet = eval(peter.pet)
```

Any insight will be appreciated...

Comment: Just one comment, because *someone* should say it: When I first read the question title, my immediate answer was "You shouldn't!"  I'm sure you know that circular references are generally a bad programing habit.  I'm not saying never use them, but in most cases they're a sign that you need to rethink the way your objects are set up.

Comment: In general I would agree with you 100%.But, there is certain instances where it is just easier to not try and flatten the structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since objects are dynamic, just add `pet` later:

```
var peter = {
    // anything else you want to set
};

var spot = {
    owner : peter
};

peter.pet = spot;
```

EDIT - removed a bad attempt at adding a function to the peter object.  To do it right, see Renan's post.

Comment: You ninja'ed me, so +1 for you.

Comment: I like this since its essentially what I decided to do. Its explicit and I don't need to go all OOP to do something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Set the reference after you created spot:

```
var peter = {
  pet : undefined
}

var spot = {
  owner : peter
}

peter.pet = spot
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var peter = {};
var spot = {owner: peter};
peter.pet = spot;
```

Alternatively, you could strenghen the typing:

```
PetOwner = function () {};
PetOwner.prototype.pet = null;

Animal = function (owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.owner.pet = this;
};
Animal.prototype.owner = null;

var peter = new PetOwner();
var spot = new Animal(peter);
```

Comment: But your function setup was better than mine, so +1 to you! :-)